# html select option SELECTED

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have in my php

```
$sel = "
    <option> one </option>
    <option> two </option>
    <option> thre </option>
    <option> four </option>
";
```

let say I have an inline URL = `site.php?sel=one`

if I didn't saved those options in a variable, I can do it this way to make one of the option be SELECTED where value is equal to `$_GET[sel]`

```
<option <?php if($_GET[sel] == 'one') echo"selected"; ?> > one </option>
<option <?php if($_GET[sel] == 'two') echo"selected"; ?> > two </option>
<option <?php if($_GET[sel] == 'three') echo"selected"; ?> > three </option>
<option <?php if($_GET[sel] == 'four') echo"selected"; ?> > four </option>
```

but the problem is, I need to save those options in a variable because I have a lot of options and I need to call that variable many times.

Is there a way to make that option be selected where `value = $_GET[sel]` ?

Comment: How is that select generated? Is it hard-coded?

Comment: When you say that you're storing them in a variable, I assume you mean an array, right?

Comment: Either what Ben said, or i asume if you shoot a variable through, you used the value assigned to the option and not the name. I would write a simple function for it, and just call it everytime, let it run through an if else statement. Saves you alot of coding or copy pasting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use the array of options, to see, which option is currently selected.

```
$options = array( 'one', 'two', 'three' );

$output = '';
for( $i=0; $i<count($options); $i++ ) {
  $output .= '<option ' 
             . ( $_GET['sel'] == $options[$i] ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' 
             . $options[$i] 
             . '</option>';
}
```

<sub>Sidenote: I would define a value to be some kind of id for each element, else you may run into problems, when two options have the same string representation.</sub>

Comment: thanks @sirko, but found some error 
no 'var' and it must be $i<count($options)

Comment: Corrected that.Too much JavaScript coding in the last weeks.

Comment: You may also use `selected` instead of `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 8):

This is simple example by using ternary operator to set selected=selected

```
<?php $plan = array('1' => 'Green','2'=>'Red' ); ?>
<select class="form-control" title="Choose Plan">
<?php foreach ($plan as $key => $value) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php echo ($key ==  '2') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach($array as $value=>$name)
{
    if($value == $_GET['sel'])
    {
         echo "<option selected='selected' value='".$value."'>".$name."</option>";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$name."</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: That'll output **two** values for the selected value. Did you mean to wrap that second echo in an `else`?

Comment: Yes it was my mistake... it should be in else part.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function and then add it to each option field to print the selected="selected".

Example

```
<option value="PHP" ' . tsw_selected('PHP', $row['anchor']) . '>PHP/PDO/SQL[+]</option>
<option value="HTML" ' . tsw_selected('HTML', $row['anchor']) . '>HTML/CSS</option>
```

Then your fun:

```
function tsw_selected( $opt, $val )
{
$sel = '';
$opt = ('' != $opt ) ? $opt : 'OTHER';
if( $opt == $val ) $sel = true;
if ( $sel ) {
    return 'selected="selected"'; } else { return ''; }
}
```

This will echo the select="selected" per true and echo '' (nothing) for false.
You could set $sel = false, but it does not matter. Booloean checks on empty as false.

Comment: This is the most simple and good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes for `$_GET['sel']` - fixing this might help solving your issue sooner :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $value => $name) {
     echo '<option value="' . htmlentities($value) . '"' . (($_GET['sel'] === $value) ? ' selected="selected"') . '>' . htmlentities($name) . '</option>';
}
```

This is fairly neat, and, I think, self-explanatory.