# Custom MetaBox Data is Saving, but Not Loading on Edit Screen

Tags: wordpress, post, loading, save

I have the following code from my first custom plugin that is creating metaboxes for a custom post type and everything is saving correctly, and everything is loading correctly on the edit page afterwards except for the "select" drop-down list elements.

The options within these select metaboxes revert back to the first option once the page reloads, although I know for a fact that it saves the data after being selected as the custom columns on custom post type view display the correct information. Once you click in to edit one of the custom post types, however, all of the text input data loads correctly, but not the select data, which reverts back to the first option item.

Here is my code(I only included one of the select metaboxes):

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box(
        "club_manufacturer-meta", 
        "Manufacturer", 
        "club_manufacturer", 
        "club_types", 
        "normal", 
        "low"
    );
}

function club_manufacturer(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $club_manufacturer = $custom["club_manufacturer"][0];
  ?>
  <label>Manufacturer:</label>
  <select name="club_manufacturer" >
    <option value="Adams" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Adams</option>
    <option value="Ben Hogan" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Ben Hogan</option>
    <option value="Callaway" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Callaway</option>
    <option value="cleveland" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Cleveland</option>
    <option value="Cobra" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Cobra</option>
    <option value="Mizuno" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Mizuno</option>
    <option value="Nike" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Nike</option>
    <option value="Odyssey" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Odyssey</option>
    <option value="Ping" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Ping</option>
    <option value="Scotty Cameron"  name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Scotty Cameron</option>
    <option value="Titleist" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Titleist</option>
    <option value="Tour Edge" name="club_manufacturer" class="<?php echo $club_manufacturer; ?>">Tour Edge</option>
  </select>
  <?php
}

function save_details(){
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "club_manufacturer", $_POST["club_manufacturer"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are not using the [attribute `selected` for `<select>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12782373/1287812).

WordPress has a handy function for that: [`selected()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected).

I would do the meta box like this (you have to build your own `$test_array`):

```
global $post;
$club_manufacturer = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'club_manufacturer', true );
$test_array = array(
    'adams' => 'Adams',
    'ben'   => 'Ben Hogan'
);

echo '<label>Manufacturer:</label>';
echo '<select name="club_manufacturer" >';

foreach( $test_array as $nick => $name )
{
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php
    printf(
        '<option value="%s" %s> %s</option>',
        $nick,
        selected( $club_manufacturer, $nick, false ),
        $name
    );
}

echo '</select>';
```

You are missing some important checks in your `save_post`, like autosave, security and correct post type. Check this example for a full working snippet: [List of Posts in a Custom Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/94701/12615).
<sub>Other good examples in this [search query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bsave_post%20%2bwp_nonce_field%20%2bdoing_autosave%20%2badd_meta_box%20is:answer), and also check the [`<plugin-development>`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pagesize=50) tag.</sub>