# Dynamically change value of a <select> inside cell of a table

Tags: html, asp.net, html-select

i'm developing an asp.net/vb.net webapp.

I've an html table with some columns.
I get the values of the cells from a database, so i've a dinamically number of rows.
In columns i need to put a  tag, because i want to allow the user to change the value of that cell.

Of course the initial value of the select should have to come from the query, but i dont know how to do this.

Something like

```
...
<td> <select selected="<%= queryresult("id").value %>">
       <option value="1"> option1 </value>
       <option value="2"> option2 </value>
</select></td>
...
```

but obv not working.
I just hope you understand what i want.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using any ASP.NET controls like GridView or DropDownList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution for your problem [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782373/html-select-option-selected) but implemented with PHP. Anyway you can do it with ASP.NET as well. Basically you have to check if the current option value has the value from the query and add *selected="selected"* to the specific option tag. Also the correct markup for a select is like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```