# keep php result as content in div

Tags: php, css, html

EDIT!!! : LINK = http://i299291.iris.fhict.nl/PHP31/DV3/DV3.php

My problem:

I've made two dropdown boxes with several options. The php code is working and the query gets the right result from the database. But now i want to compare two options.

This is what i've got so far, the problem now is the entire page refreshes when i enter the second value from the other dropdown box.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id = "leftDropdown" action= "" method="post">
    <select name="objectLinks">
      <option value="school">School</option>
      <option value="klas">Klas</option>
      <option value="geslacht">Geslacht</option>
      <option value="lengte">Lengte (CM)</option>
      <option value="kg">Gewicht (KG)</option>
      <option value="opleiding">Opleiding Ouders</option>
      <option value="leeftijdJaar">Leeftijd</option>
      <option value="interventie">Deelname interventie?</option>
      <option value="pestenVoor">Pestincidenten voor interventie</option>
      <option value="pestenNa">Pestincidenten na interventie</option>
      <option value="bmi">BMI waarde</option>
      <option value="overgewicht">Overgewicht</option>
      <option value="allochtonenPerc">Percentage Allochtonen</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="sendLinks" value="Go!">
    </form> 

    <form id = "rightDropdown" action= "" method="post">
    <select name="objectRechts">
      <option value="school">School</option>
      <option value="klas">Klas</option>
      <option value="geslacht">Geslacht</option>
      <option value="lengte">Lengte (CM)</option>
      <option value="kg">Gewicht (KG)</option>
      <option value="opleiding">Opleiding Ouders</option>
      <option value="leeftijdJaar">Leeftijd</option>
      <option value="interventie">Deelname interventie?</option>
      <option value="pestenVoor">Pestincidenten voor interventie</option>
      <option value="pestenNa">Pestincidenten na interventie</option>
      <option value="bmi">BMI waarde</option>
      <option value="overgewicht">Overgewicht</option>
      <option value="allochtonenPerc">Percentage Allochtonen</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="sendRechts" value="Vergelijk!">
    </form> 

    <div id = "leftDiv">

        <?php 

        include_once 'dv3ToDB.php'; // connect to database *local or at school's server*

        session_start();

        if(isset($_POST['sendLinks'])){
            $selectedValLinks = $_POST['objectLinks'];
            // echo "Jij selecteerde: ".$selectedVal;
            echo "<script>console.log('$selectedValLinks');</script>";
            // $_SESSION["valLinks"] = $selectedValLinks;
            // echo $_SESSION["valLinks"];

        $query = "SELECT ($selectedValLinks) FROM pesten ORDER BY ($selectedValLinks) * 1";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "Gevonden data in ".$selectedValLinks.": " . $row["$selectedValLinks"] . "<br>" ;
            }
        }else{
            echo "0 results";
        }

        }



    ?>

    </div>

    <div id = "rightDiv">
    <?php



        if(isset($_POST['sendRechts'])){
            $selectedValRechts = $_POST['objectRechts'];
            // echo "Jij selecteerde: ".$selectedVal;
            echo "<script>console.log('$selectedValRechts');</script>";
            // $_SESSION["valRechts"] = $selectedValRechts;
            // echo $_SESSION["valRechts"];

        $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database)
        or die("verbinding mislukt:".mysqli_connect_error());

        $query = "SELECT ($selectedValRechts) FROM pesten ORDER BY ($selectedValRechts) * 1";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "Gevonden data in ".$selectedValRechts.": " . $row["$selectedValRechts"] . "<br>" ;
            }
        }else{
            echo "0 results";
        }

        }


     ?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i'm running it local now, let me know if you need me to build a database online to help me out.

How can i code it so the PHP output stays in de left DIV and/or the right DIV?

Thank you so much guys and girls! :)

Comment: why are you keeping two separate forms???keep just one instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use only PHP, without any JavaScript (which could allow you to display the result from the database after selecting each option without reloading the page), I'd suggest that, after submitting one form, you add it's result as a hidden input for the other form, so you could read this variable after submitting the 2nd form.
Like this:

```
<? // Your code for getting the result of the 1st form above returns a variable $res1
// Now insert this into the 2nd form:?>
<input type="hidden" name="stored2" value="<?echo $res1;?>"/>
```

This way, you can read the variable $_POST["stored2"] after submitting the 2nd form to get what the 1st form returned before.
Do the same for the 1st form to store the results of the 2nd form if it was filled first.

This way, you can compare the results of submitting 2 forms while using only PHP.

EDIT:
You'll need to place all the database requests before the forms to use this method, and just echo the result in the div later.

Comment: I'm free to use javascript(jQuery).. 

Uhm.. i think you are right but i'm a little lost. Could you make a little more sample code? Thank you so much! :) 

The page is online now so its easier to understand for you guys ; http://i299291.iris.fhict.nl/PHP31/DV3/DV3.php

Comment: its working a little bit. Can you check my page? [My page :)](http://i299291.iris.fhict.nl/PHP31/DV3/DV3.php). It still has some problems. I think i need two requirements in the IF statement? 

Added the code to a snippet : http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=issAxY4X

Hope you can tell me what i do wrong.. im lost.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a new `<iFrame>` and then set that `<iFrame>`'s id as the target for your form.

e.g.:

```
<form ... target="newframe">
    ...
</form>

<iFrame id="newframe"></iFrame>
```

Comment: Okay, so that leaves we with getting the data i want in the iframe but also the two forms again. 

I kinda just neet the data in the iFrame and not two more forms with the same options. 

Any ideas? 

<form id = "rightDropdown" action= "" method="post" target="frameRight">
//// CODE
<form id = "leftDropdown" action= "" method="post" target="frameLeft">
//// CODE


<iframe id = "frameLeft" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="frameRight" frameborder="0"></iframe>

screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzcPUwexmjaFVVYxeDBNcmhNM3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So basically you are trying to populate two frames with one form?

Comment: The thing i need is to output the query results from the left form into one element (iFrame in your solution).

I uploaded the page to my server the way it was before you helped me. Maybe you can figure out more easily what im trying to build. I can add the PHP data into one div, but when i select an option from the other form the data goes away (because the page reloads i guess?!)

[link](http://i299291.iris.fhict.nl/PHP31/DV3/DV3.php)

Answer (score 0):

As Lal mentioned you don't need two forms, just one will work.

You need some code that updates the option to selected, if you don't want it to "stick" on page refresh.

Further reading here;
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp
and here
[html select option SELECTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782373/html-select-option-selected)

Even try Jquery;
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-dynamically-select-option-in-dropdown-menu