# Select dropdown always showing the last one selected

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have added the custom select dropdown in the post so that the admin can select the author.

```
<?PHP
    $args = array( 'post_type'=>'blogauthor','post_status' => 'publish' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    $getblogauthorId=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'blogauthor', true );// get selected when hit URL page
    $selectAuthor='';
    $selectAuthor.='<select name="blogauthor">
       <option  value="" selected="" disabled="">Select Author</option>';
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
            if($recent["ID"]==$getblogauthorId){ $authselected='selected="selected"';};
            $selectAuthor.='<option value="' .$recent["ID"].'" '.$authselected.'>' .   $recent["post_title"].'</option> ';
        }
    $selectAuthor.='</select>';


echo $selectAuthor; ?>
```

Now my issue is when I selected the author from the dropdown and clicked on update then successfully updated but when I refresh the post then I am getting the last author name select in the dropdown.

For example I have an author name called

```
ABC
PQR
XYZ
```

I selected ABC from the dropdown and updated the post and when I refresh the post then I am getting XYZ selected. It's showing the last author's name.

What is the issue in my code?

Comment: Once you set `$authselected`, it will always hold that value. Meaning every option from the selected one until the end of the dropdown will be marked as selected. You shouldn't store that result in a variable, do an inline ternary instead (in the place where you output `$authselected`).

Comment: @El_Vanja, You mean to say I have to use  like this?       $selectAuthor.='<option value="' .$recent["ID"].'" selected="selected">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</option> ';

Comment: No, you still need a condition, you just need to do it inline. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782373/html-select-option-selected).

Comment: Yes, I checked your reference link and I tried like this.         $selectAuthor.='<option value="' .$recent["ID"].'"'.( $recent["ID"] == $getblogauthorId ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ).' >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</option> ';